# How can I parse character in a File in Squeak4.1?

Tags: binary-tree, smalltalk, squeak, smacc

friend, suppose I have a file test.txt, the content of file is "1+2*3", if the fomular directly expressed in Squeak's Workspace, print it will result `9`, What I want to get is `7`
then I read the file content `1+2*3` from a file.  code like this and it works well

```
ReadFrom
"read the equation from  ./formular.txt"

| fileContents |
fileContents := FileStream 
               readOnlyFileNamed: 'test.txt' 
               do: [:f | f contents ].
^fileContents.
```

but how can I store the 5 caracters of string "1+2*3" into a collection , further I can use binary tree to calculate the equation? Do somebody can give me some hints? thanks first :)

Comment: You get 9 because you're sending messages: 1 + 2 * 3 means (1 + 2) * 3. (So if you like, message sending, including arithmetic operators, is always left-associative.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The SmaCC tutorial](http://www.refactoryworkers.com/SmaCC/Tutorial.html) ends up building pretty much what you want.

Quote from said tutorial:

> The two lines that we added to the top of the grammar mean that "+" and "-" are evaluated left-to-right and have the same precedence, which is lower than "*" and "/".

SmaCC is a full-blown parser generator for Smalltalk which may be overkill depending on your needs.

If you just want to build a simple calculator you can use the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to convert an infix mathematical expression into RPN and evaluate it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding the precedence of the operators at the top:

```
%left "+" "-";
%left "*" "/";
```