# Is there a tool for translating code from C to Smalltalk?

Tags: c, smalltalk, code-migration

friends, I have a piece of code which can perform simple add, subtraction, multiplication, division, and formula with brackets.

Is there some kind of conversion tool for translating code from C to Smalltalk?

Or any other relatively easy way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if there is a tool, but the order of operations is not directly compatible between C and Smalltalk. For example 1 + 2 * 3 returns different result.

Comment: Maybe you could use your brains?

Comment: This question seems closely related to a previous question by the OP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013028/how-can-i-parse-character-in-a-file-in-squeak4-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implementation of [SWIG for Smalltalk](http://commonsmalltalk.wikispaces.com/SWIG+Documentation). ([SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages).

Comment: Thanks Vijay :) The link helps me!

Answer (score 2):

This should be trivial to write with [PetitParser](http://www.lukas-renggli.ch/blog/petitparser-1)